# Codeigniter: How to display results from database to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been able to automatically generate remarks when scores of students are summed up.
The remarks are being stored in the database but I can't figure out a way to display it in the student report sheet.

[remark in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lf7p.jpg)

[Student report sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWB4x.jpg)

### This is my model

```php
public function add1($ss){
   $tot = $ss['total'];
   $grade = "";
   $remark = "";


   switch ($tot) {
         case $tot < 40:
             $grade = "FT";
             $remark = "FURTHER TRAINING";
                break;
            case $tot < 45 AND $tot > 39:
                $grade = "E8";
                $remark = "PASS";
                break;
            case $tot < 50 AND $tot > 44:
                $grade = "D7";
                $remark = "PASS";
                break;
            case $tot < 60 AND $tot > 49:
                $grade = "C6";
                $remark = "CREDIT";
                break;
            case $tot < 65 AND $tot > 59:
                $grade = "C5";
                $remark = "CREDIT";
                break;
            case $tot < 70 AND $tot > 64:
                $grade = "C4";
                $remark = "CREDIT";
                break;
            case $tot < 80 AND $tot > 69:
                $grade = "B3";
                $remark = "GOOD";
                break;
            case $tot < 90 AND $tot > 79:
                $grade = "B2";
                $remark = "V.GOOD";
                break;
            case $tot > 89:
                $grade = "A1";
                $remark = "EXCELLENT";
                break;
            default:
                $grade = "N/A";
                $remark = "N/A";
        }

        //var_dump($grade); die();
        $data = ['student_id'=>$ss['student_id'], 'class_id'=>$ss['class_id'], 'section_id'=>$ss['section_id'], 'subject_id'=>$ss['subject_id'], 'ca1'=>$ss['ca1'],
                'ca2'=>$ss['ca2'], 'ca3'=>$ss['ca3'], 'ca4'=>$ss['ca4'], 'ca5'=>$ss['ca5'], 'ca6'=>$ss['ca6'], 'exam'=>$ss['exam'], 'total'=>$ss['total'], 'grade'=> $grade, 'remark'=> $remark];           


        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO scores_primary (student_id, class_id, section_id, subject_id, ca1, ca2, ca3, ca4, ca5, ca6, exam, tot_score, grade, remark) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', $data);

        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
           return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        else{
           return FALSE;
        }
        }
```

### Controller

```php
function assigngrade() {
        $this->load->database('default');
        if (!$this->rbac->hasPrivilege('exam', 'can_view')) {
            access_denied();
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata('top_menu', 'Examinations');
        $this->session->set_userdata('sub_menu', 'admin/primary/assigngrade');
        $data['title'] = 'Assign Grade with Class and Subject wise';
        //$teacher = $this->teacher_model->get();
        //$teacher = $this->staff_model->getStaffbyrole(2);
        //$data['teacherlist'] = $teacher;
        $subject = $this->subject_model->get();
        $data['subjectlist'] = $subject;
        $class = $this->class_model->get();
        $data['classlist'] = $class;
        $userdata = $this->customlib->getUserData();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('class_id', 'Class Id', 'required');
        //   if(($userdata["role_id"] == 2) && ($userdata["class_teacher"] == "yes")){
        //  $data["classlist"] =   $this->customlib->getclassteacher($userdata["id"]);
        // }
        $this->load->view('layout/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/grades/assignGrade', $data);
        $this->load->view('layout/footer', $data);

        //$s['session_id'] = $this->setting_model->getCurrentSession();
//        $dt = $this->classsection_model->getDetailbyClassSection($class_id, $section_id);


        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
            $class_id = $this->input->post('class_id');
            $section_id = $this->input->post('section_id');
            $student_id = $this->input->post('pstudent_id');
            //Switch on class_id for parameters
            switch ($class_id) {
              case intval($class_id) > 14:
                $s = array(
                    'student_id' => $student_id,
                    'class_id' => $class_id,
                    'section_id' => $section_id,
                    'subject_id' => $_POST['psubject_id'],
                    'ca1' => floatval($_POST['ca1']),
                    'ca2' => floatval($_POST['ca2']),
                    'ca3' => floatval($_POST['ca3']),
                    'ca4' => floatval($_POST['tca']),
                    'ca5' => 0.0,
                    'ca6' => 0.0,
                   'exam' => $_POST['exam'],
                    'total' => array_sum([floatval($_POST['ca1']), floatval($_POST['ca2']), floatval($_POST['ca3']), floatval($_POST['exam'])]),
                );
```

### View

```php
<?php
if (!empty($subjectScores)){
   $display = '';
   $condis = '';
   $class_id = $student['class_id'];
   switch ($class_id) {
       case $class_id > 14:
           $display = '<theader><th class="col-md-4 btn-info">Subject</th><th class="col-md-1">CA1</th><th class="col-md-1">CA2</th><th class="col-md-1">CA3</th><th class="col-md-1">TCA</th><th class="col-md-1">EXAM</th><th class="col-md-1">TOTAL</th><th class="col-md-1">GRADE</th><th class="col-md-1">REMARK</th></theader>';
            foreach ($subjectScores as $key => $value) {
                $condis .= '<tr>' . '<td class="btn-warning" style="border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 3px;">'. $value['subject'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value['ca1'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value['ca2'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value['ca3'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value['ca4'] . '</td>'. '<td>' .
                                  $value['exam'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value['score'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value['grade'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value['remark'] . '</td></tr>';

                                }
                                break;
```

How do I display the generated remarks of a specific student in view?

Comment: could you post the controller codes?

Comment: I have added a bit of it. Although, I have no idea how to add the codes for displaying remarks

Comment: you didn't query to the database for the results. How will you get data from database?

Comment: Any idea on how to do that? I'm so new at all of this

Comment: See this page in the Code Igniter documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html Let me know if you need clarifications.